Jolt remove nested dict
I have the following input json (simplified; the real one has more keys):
{
    "key1":{
        "null":null
    },
    "key2":123
}

and I'd like like to simplify the null dict into a simple null like this:
{
    "key1": null,
    "key2":123
}

My latest attempt is the following jolt:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "null": "&1",
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
   }
]

But this results in:
{
  "key1": [
    {
      "null": null
    },
    null
  ],
  "key2": 123
}

because the second rule is matcing again key1 and appending again the orignal value to the same position.
Does anybody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

You might use the conditional "null" vs. otehrs("*") nested within the object such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "null": "&1",
        "*": {
          "@1": "&2" // bring the value from 2 upper level,
          // where @ matches the 1st, @1 matches the 2nd level's value
          // while &2 replicates the key from 2 upper level  
        } 
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception is :


Thx. I knew I was close, but I didn't think about using the star to trigger the mutual exclusion
